# Creating a login function

Tags: php

I'm creating a login function for a website and I'm having an issue with writing the user's information to `$_SESSION['user']`. I tried putting in some `print_r` statements to view both the `$user` variable and the `$_SESSION['user']` inside the login function and the it seems to contain the user data but when i look at the array else were in my website there is nothing in `$_SESSION['user']` array.

I have a start_session() in the top module of all my pages.

The use of the delimited text file is only for a sample and will not be used.

It's like the function writes the user data to the session but destroy itself once the function completes

Any tips are welcome

```
function login($filename, $email, $password) {
$lines = file($filename);
$headings = array();
$user = array();

foreach ($lines as $l => &$line) {
    debug_to_console("login attempt " . $l);

    $cells = explode("\t", trim($line));

    foreach ($cells as &$cell) {
        $cell = trim($cell);
        // remove whitespace
        $cell = str_replace(array('\'', '"'), '', $cell);
        //remove unwanted characters
    }
    if ($l == 0) {
        $headings = $cells;
    } else {
        if ($cells[2] == $email)//check username
        {
            if ($cells[3] == $password)// check password
            {
                foreach ($cells as $c => &$cell)// set up array of data lines
                {
                    $user[$headings[$c]] = $cell;
                }
                debug_to_console("Login Successful");
                $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            debug_to_console("no match");
        }
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you added `session_start();` as a first line of your page?

Comment: where you started the session: session_start();

Comment: text file user/password storage? *scary*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `session_start();` (usually as the first line) in each and every page where you are trying to access/edit/delete session. If you don't write it then your PHP doesn't use the session created by you.

Comment: I placed my login function before my top module containing my session_start() thanks for the help